# Suspend a Queue from MDB

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, jboss-mdb

We have an application in which we are using `JMS Queue` and an `MDB`. I want that only one message should be sent to the `MDB` from the `Queue` at a time. I mean as soon as the `MDB` gets a message from the `Queue`, it should suspend the `Queue` and once the processing is finished, the `Queue` should be resumed. Can I write code for this in my `MDB` or is there any configuration I can make in `ejb-jar.xml`?

Comment: You might be able to adjust the pool to size 1 and only have 1 bean do the work.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do the same with GlassFish once. You can tell your application server to create on consumer per MDB and then your MDB will be processing one message at a time. To do that in glassfish:

> Open GlassFish Server Administration Console, navigate to the
>   Configuration -> configuration-name -> EJB Container node and then select
>   the MDB Settings tab.

Specify:

`Maximum Pool Size:` **1**

And thats it for the glassfish. Restart server and you are good to go. Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2431/abebw.html#abedi) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152654/jms-and-messagedriven-ejb-bean) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your MDB as:

```
@MessageDriven(name = "SingleThreadedMdb ", activationConfig = {
   @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
   @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue/myQueue"),
   @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
   @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "1"),
   @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "consumerWindowSize", propertyValue = "0")
})
public class SingleThreadedMdb implements MessageListener {

  @Override
  public void onMessage(Message message) {
  }

}
```

Configure the queue in `standalone-full.xml` as:

```
<address-setting match="jms.queue.myQueue">
  <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
  <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
  <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
  <max-delivery-attempts>1</max-delivery-attempts>
  <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
  <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
  <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
</address-setting>
```

Under jms destinations add:

```
<jms-queue name="myQueue">
  <entry name="/queue/myQueue"/>
  <durable>true</durable>
</jms-queue>
```